# Make sure the GraphQL service is installed and available (Sitecore 10 CLI)

Tags: graphql, serialization, sitecore-cli

When I try to use one of these commands

`dotnet sitecore ser push`

`dotnet sitecore ser pull`

`dotnet sitecore ser publish`

I got this error

`Make sure the GraphQL service is installed and available`

[image: Make sure the GraphQL service is installed and available]

I installed the Sitecore Management Services by following the steps on this web page
https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/100/developer-tools/en/sitecore-management-services.html

Anyone can help?